# Scroll through command output without a temporary file

Tags: command-line

I am wandering if there is a way to read the full output of a command when it uses more than the screen. I am currently having to output the command into a file, and then using `nano` to scroll through it.

E.g. `$ ls -Al /etc/` only displays the end of the output and cuts of the rest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `less` less is a pager, it allows you to view a page at a time. e.g.

```
command | less
ls -Al /etc | less
```

The most common command while in less are:

- <kbd>enter</kbd> advance one line
- <kbd>space</kbd> advance one page
- <kbd>q</kbd> quit / exit help
- <kbd>h</kbd> help

see `man less` for more info, like how to search.

Answer (score 1):

That's possible by pressing <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>pg up</kbd>.

More information on scrollback and the scrollback buffer can be found [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/145050/what-exactly-is-scrollback-and-scrollback-buffer).

Comment: This will depend on the terminal (emulator).

Comment: It works for me.

Comment: @richard Which one(s) don't implement a scrollback buffer?

Comment: @Jan I can not list them all, but some examples are the console `alt` `ctrl` `F1`, old or low resource using emulators, and some physical terminals.

Comment: @richard, the linux console does have a scrollback buffer, it just only works for the current vt, and is lost on vt switch.

Answer (score 0):

Pipe any command's output into `less` and it will allow pagination, searching nd whatnot.

`ls -lA /etc | less`

As 'less' is displaying your text, hit `h` for help, read and ponder.
`man less` - more to read.