# How to increase the Yakuake terminal scrollback buffer?

Tags: terminal-emulator

The [buffer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/145050/what-exactly-is-scrollback-and-scrollback-buffer) appears to be limited to around 1000 lines — less than with some other terminal emulators I've used and thus I often have to pipe the full output to a file or to the clipboard. Is there a built-in setting to display more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to edit the Scroll back -> Fixed Size field. In case you don't have  a profile already, you need to create one and set it as default .

[image: screenshot]