# To what file or tty device does terminal's output get saved to?

Tags: terminal

I'm an intermediate level user. When I'm using terminal and it's scrolling text off the top of its window… *where does the text go?* It must be being saved *somewhere,* but I can't wrap my head around how to ask the question in the first place. Are there text files created that can be accessed?

Here's a weirder question: during a live terminal session, is there a way to scroll back into the old, historical output and, during my live session, can I have searchable control over what's in that virtual space, using commands similar to vi or vim?

It's not the vi command history I'm wanting to navigate through—*available at .viminfo*—it's its *output* into which I'm wanting to dive.

I'm somewhat familiar with tty devices, but not enough to know how they relate to permanent text files, or temporary files being appended to during the course of a vi session, or how I might open a second terminal session to see a different file to see the accumulated summary of the other terminal window's collected history.

Comment: Are you perhaps asking about the terminal's scrollback buffer? if so, you may find this helpful [What exactly is scrollback and scrollback buffer?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/145050/what-exactly-is-scrollback-and-scrollback-buffer)

Comment: (The ability to search the scrollback buffer depends on the application that's providing it. If it's the default Linux kernel tty, then to you'll have to use screen like suggested in ^)